# orderby ignored by wp_query

Tags: wp-query, order, sort

With the following code, I do not get the result set ordered by titles. No matter what values I give to 'orderby' and 'order', I get the same ordering. The parameters seem to be ignored (or overridden?) by something else..

Any idea how I troubleshoot this one? Is there a specific filter I should be looking at, that some plugin could be overriding this via?

Should the code below work out of the box? IF it looks correct, something must be interfering.

```
$args = Array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
    'category_name' => 'reviews'
    'posts_per_page' => '999'
    'orderby' => 'title'
    'order"' => 'ASC'
    'post_status' => 'publish'
)

$customloop = new WP_Query();
$customloop->query($args);

while ($customloop->have_posts()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you have an extra quote after order in your args. That affecting it?